# Wifi stops working after 10 seconds

Tags: networking, wireless, 19.10, atheros

I found a question really similar to this one but that one didnt get an answer so that is why im asking it here again. Everytime I connect to my wifi network it only works for about 10 seconds then it stops working even though it says it is still connected. When i disconnect and connect again it works for another 5 to 10 seconds.

Things I have tried:

- MTU changes
- DNS changes
- Iwlwifi
- Upgrading dist
- Checking kernel version
- Powersaving
- Different config changes

General info:

- Lenovo laptop
- Qualcomm Atheros
- Ubuntu 19.10
- 5.4.0-14

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is a very typical problem, which is caused not by any soft/hardware on your machine, but the interference on your router's radio signal. It means that other radio devices (most probably, routers of your neighbors, if you live in condominium) are distorting your router's WiFi waves. Try to change the channel, on which it work. This can be done at the Wireless settings section in your router administration panel. There are several channels, try all of them until problem solved or the interference hypothesis is eliminated.